# How to make a model attribute persists only in one controller in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

How to make a model attribute only persists in one controller, when requests go to another controller , this model attribute will be reset. In other words, the model attribute will be shared between the @RequestMapping annonated methods in one controller only.

Comment: what is your business case? can you explain this requirement more clearly with example?

Comment: How are you using `@ModelAttribute`? What are you annotating? Please share a code snippet.